# jQuery dual animation combine

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I'm really struggling with a jQuery animation.

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7LL/5/) where I have posted the question. http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7LL/5/

I basically have 2 separate animations running, and I some how need to combine them so they run in unison and don't get confused.

See code below which works, but its not running great as the animations seem to run after each other.

```
    $('#sidebar-inner, #latest-tweet').hover(function() {
        $("#wrapper").stop().animate({ left: "-178px" }, 300);
        $("#sidebar-slider").stop().animate({ width: "512px" }, 300);
        $("#latest-tweet").stop().animate({ width: "512px" }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $("#wrapper").stop().animate({ left: "0" }, 300);
        $("#sidebar-slider").stop().animate({ width: "334px" }, 300);
        $("#latest-tweet").stop().animate({ width: "334px" }, 300);     
    });

    $('#latest-tweet').hover(function() {
        $('#latest-tweet').animate({ top: "-163px" }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('#latest-tweet').animate({ top: "-1px" }, 300);       
    });
```

I've created a simplified version in a the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zc7LL/5/) so you can get the idea of what is going wrong. It's like I need to merge these functions both together, but my attempts are not working at all.

Comment: What are you trying to do?
Could you exactly explain what you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, by adding code in each of your `.hover()` functions to animate each of the elements in the DOM you can get a seamless animation out of your page: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Zc7LL/9/

```
var $sidebarInner = $('#sidebar-inner'),
    $latestTweet  = $("#latest-tweet");
$sidebarInner.hover(function() {
    $sidebarInner.stop().animate({ right: "0" }, 300);
    $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", right : "0"}, 300);
}, function() {
    $sidebarInner.stop().animate({ right : "-250px" }, 300);
    $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", right : "-250px"}, 300);
});

$latestTweet.hover(function() {
    $sidebarInner.stop().animate({ right : "0" }, 300);
    $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-163px", right : "0" }, 300);
}, function() {
    $sidebarInner.stop().animate({ right : "-250px" }, 300);
    $latestTweet.stop().animate({ top : "-1px", right : "-250px" }, 300);        
});
```

Comment: dude this looks amazing, I cannot thank you enough man!!!! It works so much better now :-) Though now with these variables, on the $latestTweet second function alternation, even though the top is -1px, when you mouse off the grey onto the blue, the grey#latestTweet doesnt slide down until you roll off the blue entirely? Is this ment to happen? Appreciate your help.

Comment: I added an edit that isn't accepted yet, but simply add `top:"-1px"` to the line `$latestTweet.stop().animate({right : "0"}, 300);` in the first hover function to get the grey to slide down.

Comment: Thanks for the code suggestion @andbeyond. I updated the code above and the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/Zc7LL/9/

Comment: Again, big thanks Jasper and andbeyond - cheers for taking interest and giving quality source to work from, I have integrated it into my project plus extra, and can understand fully whats going on. Cheers :)