# can i add an animation to a currently running animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, svg

I have a line chart that looks similar to a stock market graph, the line going up and down over a period of time.  I'm overlaying a narrow vertical bar (svg/rect) on top of the line chart and sliding the bar along the X-axis by animating the "left" value.  It works great.

I was just asked if the height of the bar could follow the height of the line chart as it's sliding along the x-axis.  I have the data so I just set up an interval every 1/10th of a second to change the height of the svg/rect.

So the bar is sliding left to right via jquery.animate() and the height of the bar changes based on the data value via javascript:setInterval and jqeury.css().  This also works great.

Now I'm being asked if I can make the height of the bar not be so jerky as it changes.  Normally I'd change the height using .animate(), but the bar is already moving from left to right using .animate().  I essentially want to have a nested animate.  While the bar is animating left to right, I want to animate the height of the bar.

The step function parameter of .animate() was about the closest thing I could see to accomplish this but that won't really work.  It's mainly used to modify the existing animation, not add a new animation.

Any other ideas?

**Edit:** One thought I had was to animate the outer SVG from left to right and then animate the inner `<rect>`'s height.  That way it could slide while the height was changing.  However, animate is for CSS styles and the 'height' CSS style does not work on a `<rect>`.  For example:

```
<rect height='100'/>
<rect style='height:100px;'/>
```

The first `<rect>` will correctly draw a 100 (unit) tall rectangle.  The second `<rect>` will ignore the height style and the height will be 0 as if I didn't specify it.  So I can't animate the height of the `<rect>`.

Comment: Running out the door or I would research this more. [Maybe this can help out?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302425/jquery-dual-animation-combine)

Answer (score 0):

The Jquery method animate allows for 'step' in its paramaters in json format which is a function called in every step of the animation interval ex:

```
$('selector').animate({
height: '+=10px'
 }, {
duration: 400,
step: function() {
    $(this).children('selector').animate({
        width: '+=10px'
    });
}

   });
```

the step function can be whatever but it can be a nested animation on the same selectors or different selctors that is called every interval of the animation

Answer (score 0):

In the early days of SVG SMIL, it seemed a bit jerkier than JavaScript based animation, but circa 2008 that stopped being true. If you don't care about IE support, then SMIL will probably give a much smoother effect than javascript-based packages like JQuery etc. It also makes it far easier to animate with different timing loops and periodicities  and new animate children may be appended to the DOM with relative ease. The SMIL animation module is much more stable and expressive currently than the CSS cousin that tries to borrow from its ideas.